# java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to copy a image from Photos app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a image from android Photos app using the share option that point to my PhotoGetFromGallery activity. Here is the code:

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}

public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    String sourcePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    if(isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            String destinationImagePath = sd + "/Pictures/MyAppImgFolder/";
            File source = new File(data, sourcePath);
            String fileName = source.getName();
            File destination = new File(sd, destinationImagePath + fileName);
            try {
                copy(source, destination);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("COPY IMAGE ERROR", e.toString() + ". Destination Path is " + destinationImagePath.toString() + " and Source path is "+ sourcePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`sourcePath` string returns the correct image path (ex. */storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20150413_114608.jpg*). However, I'm getting the `FileNotFoundException` because `Environment.getDataDirectory()` returns */data/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20150413_114608.jpg*.

Here is my log:

```
E/COPY IMAGE ERROR﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20150413_114608.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). Destination Path is /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyAppImgFolder/ and Source path is /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20150413_114608.jpg
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My question is how can I get, if possible, any path of images stored at Photos app or Android Gallery?

Comment: Convert to String -> `if(String.startsWith("\\data")){ String = String.subString(5, String.length);}` -> Convert String to URI -> Proceed like nothing happened

Comment: You could be more specific? I am not very familiar with Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Follows the code that works . Thanks to Chris Stratton for guiding me in this matter.

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String destinationImagePath = sd + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM;
File imagePath = new File(destinationImagePath);
File source = new File(sourcePath);
String fileName = source.getName();
File destination = new File(destinationImagePath + fileName);
   if (!imagePath.exists()) {
       imagePath.mkdirs();
       try {
            copy(source, destination);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success! File was copy from " + sourcePath + " to " + destinationImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("COPY IMAGE ERROR", e.toString());
       }
   } else if(destination.exists() && !destination.isDirectory()){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is already on your image folder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using getDataDirectory - you are already being handed a complete path, starting with "/storage"  Use the single argument File() constructor passing only the sourcePath, like this:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String destinationImagePath = sd + "/Pictures/MyAppImgFolder/";
//sourcePath is already a full path name
File source = new File(sourcePath);
//redundant String fileName = source.getName();

File destination = new File(destinationImagePath + sourcePath);
//You are proposing many new subdirectories, so you must create them
destination.getParentFile()makeDirs();

//now you can continue with your copy attempt
```

Comment: Now I'm geting the following error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyAppImgFolder/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20150413_114608.jpg: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I accidentally had you calling mkdirs() on the target rather than its parent, and still had you doubling the source path.  This should be better, but you may want to go further and strip in unimportant beginning of the source path (which also seems to be on the external storage) out before you include it in the destination path.  You may want to go in with the adb shell and carefuly rm -rf /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyAppImgFolder to clean up the resulting mess.